# Carousel in XWiki

Tags: carousel, xwiki

I am using XWiki as a backend my CMS.
On one of the pages i would like to include a Carousel with few pictures.
I do not really have any preference on which implementation to use.

I would be happy to use a solution such as on the [xwiki.org](http://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome) or [here](http://alienoretguillaume.com/xwiki/bin/view/Carousel/Slider)

I am looking for an instruction how to include such a carousel on XWiki.

Answer (score 1):

The carrousel you mention is available in the Leiothrix skin

http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Leiothrix+Skin

You can also look at the code itself

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Gallery Macro](http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Gallery+Macro) or the [Photo Album Macro](http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Photo+Album+Macro) is all you need?